# Seperation of UI Laye from the domain layer

Tags: oop, user-interface, design-patterns

In the book **Applying UML and Design Patterns**, it is written that in a layered system, we delegate requests from the UI layer to the domain layer. An example of this is: If someone enters something in window and requests an operation on this newly input then this request should be delegated to domain/logical layer.

This is ok but suppose i want to show the result back in a window after adding two numbers for example, in this case , my domain/logical  layer must know about the UI layer interface and then my representation is not independent of the view.

How do i solve this problem?

[image]

Is it possible to avoid birectional association between `UI` and `Domain Layer`?
The problem is that the requests from users are caught in `GUI` and then these must do some calculations and update `GUI`.

Comment: Your domain/logic layer doesn't have to access the UI directly.  It can, instead, return plain old data, and then the UI can handle presenting that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I got your problem right.

One approach would be using one of the various MVC (model view controller) approaches:
in a window (view), you see your input boxes or whatever.
When you enter your numbers there, the request is delegated to the controller.
The controller now decised what to to - it will hand over to a model (depending on the request).
With the result from the model, the controller may instantiate a new view.

Other patterns could be PAC (presentation abstraction control) or the MVP (model view presenter).
You find a brief explanations on wikipedia (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and deeper explanation here: https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html